# Send text from website to whatsapp web

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, share, whatsapp

Currently I am sending text from my mobile website to whatsapp using

```
%a{:href => "whatsapp://send?text=#{url}", :id=>"whatsapp", :class=>"btn btn-success share1"}
```

I cannot open this link on pc(website), if I use this

```
%a{:href => "https://web.whatsapp.com//send?text=#{url}", :id=>"whatsapp", :class=>"btn btn-success share1"}
```

I am able to open whatsapp through whatsapp (web page) but I am not able to send text as I was able to do in mobile.

What should I do?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work. Use a client like [whatsapi](https://github.com/ongair/whatsapi).

Install by placing in your Gemfile and run bundle:

```
gem 'whatsapi'
```

Then put this in a method and just call it from a URL somewhere:

```
require 'whatsapi'
client = WhatsApi::Client.new("1234567", "whatsapp_user", "nickname")
client.connect
client.login "your password"
```